# neither...nor with articles

Tags: neither-nor

How would you use neither...nor when articles are involved?
For instance: "My pet was neither a cat nor a dog."
It sounds better to say "My pet was neither green nor blue" than "neither a...or a..." so I was wondering if there was some rule about this?
Regarding the first example, "My pet was neither a cat or a dog" sounds more natural to me, for some reason.

Comment: "Neither cat nor dog" would work.

Comment: *Green* and *blue* are adjectives, hence no articles. With your nouns *cat* and *dog*, the articles are optional, however the sense is slightly different without them. The article-less *cat* and *dog* mean "*catkind*" and "*dogkind*."

Comment: Ah, yeah—so is it only grammatically correct to use neither...nor with adjectives?

Comment: No.  "My pet was neither a cat nor a dog" is fine. It may sound a little off because it's a rather unexpected thing to say, standalone. It would be better after some facilitating context.

Comment: There's nothing at all unusual about the first sentence in the question. So, the question is based on a faulty premise. (In fact, the final sentence is not right at at all.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Hi. What's wrong with the second sentence: *My pet was neither green nor blue*? Perhaps the pet, now deceased, was red.

Comment: @RichardKayser There isn't anything wrong with that sentence either. My point is that there isn't anything wrong with anything—other than the final sentence.

Comment: @JasonBassford 10-4. I get it now. I thought the use of *or* rather than *nor* was a typo, but maybe not ...

Answer (score 1):

As @Edwin Ashworth says, we need some context. This is always needed because English is a context-dependent language.

**Neither a P nor a Q**

John: Do you have any pets?

Mary: I have one pet.

John: Let me guess. I bet it's a dog or a cat.

Mary: No it's neither a cat nor a dog. (This refers to a specific individual)

John: Is it a rabbit?

Mary: Yes!

**Neither P nor Q**

Mary: My goodness! What kind of animal is that?

John: I don't know. It looks weird.

Mary: All I can say is it's neither cat nor dog.  (This refers to the species)

John: I think it is some kind of predator whatever it is.

Comment: Yes, you have put your finger on what needs explaining, and made it very clear.  There is an expression that illustrates a very slightly way of using the negative disjunction without an article, when we say that a thing, animal or person is 'neither flesh, fish not fowl', meaning it is indefinably weird.